# iphone7 js history.replaceState

Tags: javascript, iphone, replace

I created a product list page and have this bit of JS to keep url reflecting the item that the user is looking at (so the back button should go back to that point on the page)

```
setInterval(function() {
    itm = jQuery('.my_item:visible:last').attr('id');
    jQuery('.my_item').each(function(){if((jQuery(this).offset().top + jQuery(this).height()) > jQuery(window).scrollTop()){
         itm = jQuery(this).attr('id'); 
        return false;
    }});
    history.replaceState({} ,window.location.href.split('itm=')[0] , window.location.href.split('itm=')[0] + '&itm='+ itm);
},200);
```

this works 100% on my desktop chrome browser and on android and Iphone 6 and under but for some reason on iphone7 this does not work it seems that the URL is not always updated, any ideas why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know history.replaceState is forbidden in iPhone because of security reasons. But changing window.location.hash is not, so you can make the same functionality using the hash instead of query parameter.